# Story object doesn't expire when User post a story feed

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How do i set time for a story to expire at a certain time when users post a story, I been working on this project where i want users to be able to post a story feed for a period of time then it get deleted.
Here is my story model. actually i don't really understand the way to make the post story of users to expired at a certain  time like after 48 hours the post should be deleted from the story feed.

```
class StoryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            expire__lt=Now()
        )

class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    story = models.FileField(upload_to="stories",blank=True,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="ImageStorie", blank=True,null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expire = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="like")
    image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='images', processors=[ResizeToFill(500, 300)],
                                    format="JPEG",
                                    options={'quality':100})


    objects = StoryManager()
```

This my view for the story model, but the story doesn't delete after 48 hours when its been post? can someone kindly help me with this!

```
def storie(request):
    context = {}
    videos = Story.objects.filter(expire__lt=Now()).delete()
    context['video'] = videos
    return render(request,'feed/feed.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your view is basically filtering out all instances of `Story` that are older than `Now()`. You could filter the queryset by a delta to `created` which is the timestamp of the creation of a story instance.

```
# View

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def storie(request):

    # Delta of 48 hours from creation
    time_delta = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=48)

    # Apply filter to queryset
    videos = Story.objects.filter(created__lt=time_threshold)

    context = {
        'videos': videos
    }

    return render(request,'feed/feed.html', context)
```

Note that this removes all Stories older than 48 hours form the story feed / the queryset. In the database they are of course still persistent.